# jquery fancybox for html pages

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I was wondering if it is possible to use jquery fancybox to show different html pages.
I am not so much concerned about linking external pages, just the ability to navigate the pages I want to show.

http://flipboard.com does that on their landing page but mostly changing images.

I wanted to see if it is possible to build a landing page with navigation on the side similar to flipboard.com use jquery fancybox to show the next pages.

Any code samples or pointers would be helpful.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use the *Iframe* feature mentioned in [the Fancybox homepage](http://fancybox.net).

See also the second code example here: http://zfranciscus.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/managing-iframe-using-fancybox/

Answer (score 1):

Flipboard uses an open source jQuery plugin called [CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/). You could download the same plugin and see if it works with HTML pages as well as images, or if it's possible to adapt it for your own site.

Comment: I see that most of the examples shown are for showing images. Is it possible to load html pages using crossslide?